# Is it better to write "the affected people" or "the people affected"?

Tags: word-order

Which (if any) is better:

1. We have spoken with the affected people.
2. We have spoken with the people affected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatical, but "we have spoken with *the people affected*" sounds more idiomatic to my ears.

Google Ngram Viewer [appears to agree](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20affected%20people%2C%20the%20people%20affected&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20affected%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20people%20affected%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I would check out those Ngram results ... "the people affected" is probably bumped up by "the people affected *by*" or the "the people affected *with*" when the OP's examples here don't have any adjunct.

Answer (score -1):

Affected is an adjective.  It is normal to place an adjective before the noun (your first case) but when the adjective forms part of a reduced relative clause it is acceptable to position the adjective after the noun.  As an example, the following is acceptable, "I'd like to speak to all the people involved."

Comment: See [Adjectives and noun modifiers in English – article](http://www.onestopenglish.com/grammar/grammar-reference/adjectives/adjectives-and-noun-modifiers-in-english-article/144843.article)

Comment: The relative clause version being, "I'd like to speak to all the people who were involved."